# Linked List object is not storing string input which results in a blank Link list

Tags: java, object, linked-list, queue

I am having issues storing data typed in the keyboard to my link list Add method.  The point of this program is to implement a queue using a linked list.  The only thing is, that the class constructor accepts two parameters for every node in the list (their Name and link).

here is my class file so far...

```
public class linklist_MP
{
 //Private intance variables and links
   private linklist_MP front;
   private linklist_MP rear;
   private linklist_MP link;
   private linklist_MP previous;
   private String data;
   private int count = 0;
   private boolean flag;



//Construtor for Each Node's link and parameter type
  public linklist_MP(String input, linklist_MP intiallink)
  {
  data = input;
  link = intiallink;

  }

public boolean listEmpty()
{
  flag = false;

  if(count == 0)
  {
     flag = true;
  }

  return flag;
}

public void addList(String input)
{
  //Creating new node with read input
  //linklist_MP node = new linklist_MP(input, null);

  if(count == 0)
  {
      front = new linklist_MP(input, front);
  }
  else
  {
     previous = front;

     while(previous.link != null)
     {
        previous = previous.link;
     }

     rear = previous;

     rear.link = new linklist_MP(input, null); 

  }


  count++;

}

 public String toString() 
 {
   String result = data + " ";
   if (link != null) 
   {
      result += link.toString();
   }
   return result;
 }
}
```

And Here is my Driver File which makes a object of my class and stores in the user data..

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class linklistDriver_MP
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {

  String input;

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


  System.out.println("Just add a String: ");
  input = keyboard.nextLine();


  linklist_MP object = new linklist_MP(input, null);

  object.addList(input);

  System.out.println("Add another String: ");
  input = keyboard.nextLine();

  object.addList(input);

  System.out.println("\nTime to print the list out: ");
  object.toString();
 }
}
```

Basically when my print method is called in the driver file to print all the nodes in the link list, nothing comes out and the list prints blank. I am trying to figure out why that is since I used the object in my driver to add the two strings the user enters in the keyboard as the add method is called... Thanks in-advance!

Comment: Your linked list class is all jacked up to the point that you should completely start over.  You need to review how to implement a LinkedList.  For one this line makes absolutely no sense: `front = new linklist_MP(input, front);`.  `front` is null, so you just set the "initiallink" to null in the `front` node.  I don't know know what that's supposed to mean, but I'm quite sure it's not what you intended.

Comment: lol thanks for input.  But that line: `front = new linklist_MP(input, front);` is to identify the first node since it points to itself in the linked list where the last node in the list has a link of null.  Atleast thats what i was going for since i can only add to the rear of the list.

Comment: I understand what `front` and `rear` are _supposed_ to be.  What I don't understand is why you have `link` as a field.  Like I said, when you call `new linklist_MP(input, front);`, `front` is `null` and thus it sets `front`'s `link` to `null`.

Comment: yeah i see what you mean Jared.  Now it makes sense why almost every example of linked list implementation involved a constructor with "No link-field parameters." I think by me changing my constructor up and setting my pointers to null like you said will make this less complicated for the simple structure that it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your program does not output anything is because you call the method toString() but you never print the output of this method.

However it looks as if your linked list structure is also way off. Essentially a linked list data structure consists of a piece of data and a link to the next node in the sequence.

You however have multiple other nodes linked in your node. You should try to simplify your design because a linked list is a very simple data structure but I think you have overcomplicated it.

Comment: To say this is over complicated is an understatement (sorry for the commentary Manny, but I figure, what are comments for, right?).

Comment: Haha well the comments are here for a reason my friend and you are just being honest here.  But seriously Jared, thanks for the blunt honesty! lol I needed it so questions like this wont ever pop into existence again!

Comment: And i agree with you Kyle I definitely over complicated things here.